# How can I use MongoDB in jsp file?

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp

I want to use mongoDB in jsp file.
But I don't know how I can use mongotemplate in jsp.

I imported 
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate  or
org.springframework.data.mongodb.*
It worked in java file. but not in jsp file.

Comment: JSP is for generating views (HTML), not for connecting to a database.

Comment: I want to use image tag with jsp file like <img src='/imageout.jsp'> When I use java, It was so slow to get datas from the server.
Or, I want to know how connection makes faster.
I get byte[] image data from mongodb, and change base64 type and send it to html page. But when I send it to html page, it takes long time.

Comment: Why do you think JSP is faster? It's a java servlet after all.

Comment: Base64 Encoding is a bad idea. It subverts the whole caching mechanism in browsers that would otherwise stop images being loaded with every request when unchanged. Better to have endpoints that "pretend" to just be regular files and serve up your image content that way.